# Optimal blocks lying strategy

Tags: algorithms

I want to get max lines from tetris board

blocks:

```
#  #  #  ##   ##  ###  ##
#  #  #  ##  ##    #    ##
# ##  ##   
# 

I J   L  O   S    T   Z
```

for example board:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
##........
##..##....
##..##..##
##.#######
##.#######
##.#####..
```

and

ZOIO

means seqence for blocks.

I don't have idea how to optimal lying blocks that I want to get max lines :/

Answer (score 1):

In the general case where the width of the playing area is variable, this is an NP-hard problem, so you shouldn't expect to be able to find optimal solutions.

The classical paper is [Tetris is Hard, Even to Approximate](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0210020) by Demaine, Hohenberger, and Liben-Nowell (2002).

Comment: playing width is always 10, and initial systems are always selected so that there is no possibility of inserting the block into the center of the building

Comment: and max number of blocks is 5